# tensor product of a graded vector space and an object in k-linear category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, tensor-products, triangulated-categories

In the book "Fourier-Mukai Transforms in Algebraic Geometry", the author has been using the following terminology quite a few times in the first two chapters (Proof of Lemma 1.58, Definition 2.72, etc.), and I can't make sense of it. After digging further, I think here is the correct way to phrase the question:

Fix a field $k$ and let $\mathscr{A}$ be a $k$-linear abelian (or triangulated) category. Let $V^\bullet$ be a ($\mathbb{Z}$-)graded vector space and $E \in \mathscr{A}$. Consider $E$ as a complex concentrated at degree 0 and define
$$V^\bullet \otimes_k E = \bigoplus_i V^i \otimes_k E[-i]$$
What doesn't make sense to me is the tensor product on the right (and hence the left). Shifted or not, you are taking the tensor product of a vector space with an abstract object in a category. How can that even make sense?

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of this is
$$
V \otimes_k E := \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\dim(V)} E.
$$
Another (functorial) point of view is that
$$
- \otimes_k E \colon \mathrm{Vect} \to \mathcal{A}
$$
is the left adjoint functor to
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(E, -) \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathrm{Vect}.
$$

Comment: Okay, but does the existence of left adjoint always guarantee, or does it depend on $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: You can use the first formula as the definition of the functor and then just check that this functor is left adjoint.